# List, tuples or dictionary, differences and usage, How can I store info in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm very new in python (I usually write in php). I want to understand how to store information in an associative array, and if you can explain me whats the difference of "tuples", "arrays", "dictionary" and "list" will be wonderful (I tried to read different source but I still not caching it).

So This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

import csv
import string

nidless_keys = dict()
nidless_keys = ['test_string1','test_string2'] #this contain the string to 
                                               # be searched in linesreader
data = {'type':[],'id':[]} #here I want to store my information

with open('path/to/csv/file.csv',newline="") as    csvfile:
    linesreader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar="|") 
    for row in linesreader: #every line in this csv have a url like     
                            #www.test.com/?test_string1&id=123456
            current_row_string = str(row)
            for needle in nidless_keys:
                    current_needle  = str(needle)
                    if current_needle in current_row_string:
                    data[current_needle[current_row_string[-8:]]) += 1 # also I
#need to count per every id how much rows there are.
```

In conclusion:

```
my_data_stored = [current_needle][current_row_string[-8]]
current_row_string[-8]  is a url which the last 8 digit of the url is an ID.
```

So the array should looks like this at the end of the script:

```
 test_string1 = 123456 = 20
              = 256468 = 15
 test_string2 = 123155 = 10
```

Edit 1:

- Which type I need here to store the information?
- Can you tell me how to resolve this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to count how many times an ID in combination with a test string occurs.
There can be multiple ID/count combinations associated with every test string.

This suggests that you should use a dictionary indexed by the test strings to store the results. In that dictionary I would suggest to store `collections.Counter` objects.

This way, you would have to add a special case when a key in the results dictionary isn't found to add an empty `Counter`. This is a common problem, so there is a specialized form of dictionary in the `collections` module called `defaultdict`.

```
import collections
import csv

# Using a tuple for the keys so it cannot be accidentally modified
keys = ('test_string1', 'test_string2')
result = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)

with open('path/to/csv/file.csv',newline="") as csvfile:
    linesreader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar="|")
    for row in linesreader:
        for key in keys:
            if key in row:
                id = row[-6:] # ID's are six digits in your example.
                # The first index is into the dict, the second into the Counter.
                result[key][id] += 1
```

---

There is an even easier way, by using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).
Since you seem to treat every row in a CSV file as a string, there is little need to use the CSV reader, so I'll just read the whole file as text.

```
import re

with open('path/to/csv/file.csv') as datafile:
    text = datafile.read()

pattern = r'\?(.*)&id=(\d+)'
```

The `pattern` is a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). This is a large topic in and of itself, so I'll only cover *briefly* what it does. (You might also want to check out the [relevant HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)) At first glance it looks like complete gibberish, but it is actually a complete language.

In looks for two things in a line. Anything between `?` and `&id=`, and a sequence of digits after `&id=`.

I'll be using [IPython](https://ipython.org/)  to give an example.
(If you don't know it, check out IPython. It is *great* for trying things and see if they work.)

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: pattern = r'\?(.*)&id=(\d+)'

In [3]: text = """www.test.com/?test_string1&id=123456
   ....: www.test.com/?test_string1&id=123456
   ....: www.test.com/?test_string1&id=234567
   ....: www.test.com/?foo&id=234567
   ....: www.test.com/?foo&id=123456
   ....: www.test.com/?foo&id=1234
   ....: www.test.com/?foo&id=1234
   ....: www.test.com/?foo&id=1234"""
```

The `text` variable points to the string which is a mock-up for the contents of your CSV file.
I am assuming that:

- every URL is on its own line
- ID's are a sequence of digits.

If these assumptions are wrong, this won't work.

Using `findall` to extract every match of the pattern from the text.

```
In [4]: re.findall(pattern, test)
Out[4]: 
[('test_string1', '123456'),
 ('test_string1', '123456'),
 ('test_string1', '234567'),
 ('foo', '234567'),
 ('foo', '123456'),
 ('foo', '1234'),
 ('foo', '1234'),
 ('foo', '1234')]
```

The `findall` function returns a list of 2-tuples (that is key, ID pairs). Now we just need to count those.

```
In [5]: import collections

In [6]: result = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)

In [7]: intermediate = re.findall(pattern, test)
```

Now we fill the result dict from the list of matches that is the intermediate result.

```
In [8]: for key, id in intermediate:
   ....:     result[key][id] += 1
   ....:  

In [9]: print(result)
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'foo': Counter({'1234': 3, '123456': 1, '234567': 1}), 'test_string1': Counter({'123456': 2, '234567': 1})})
```

So the complete code would be:

```
import collections
import re

with open('path/to/csv/file.csv') as datafile:
    text = datafile.read()

result = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
pattern = r'\?(.*)&id=(\d+)'
intermediate = re.findall(pattern, test)

for key, id in intermediate:
    result[key][id] += 1
```

This approach has two advantages.

- You don't have to know the keys in advance.
- ID's are not limited to six digits.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer, can you tell me please how I can output or print the "collections.defaultdict" to get the results? btw, nice solution with the regular (I'll not implement it, because I have allergy to them).
Do you know some good place to start with Python?

Comment: The easiest way to get get a decent formatted output without much effort is to use `pprint.pprint(result)`. Otherwise you have to iterate over the result `dict` and then iterate over each `Counter`. Then you can format the result however you like. See the documentation for a `dict` on ways to iterate over it. As for learning Python, I found Mark Lutz's book "Learning Python" very useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I saw the pprint function manual and I already searched the book, and hope to start study quickly.

Answer (score 0):

A brief summary of the python data types you mentioned:

- A *dictionary* is an associative array, aka hashtable.
- A *list* is a sequence of values.
- An *array* is essentially the same as a list, but limited to basic datatypes. My impression is that they only exists for performance reasons, don't think I've ever used one. If performance is that critical to you, you probably don't want to use python in the first place.
- A *tuple* is a fixed-length sequence of values (whereas lists and arrays can grow).

Comment: Hi @Henning Koehler, Thanks for your response, 
When you say "A dictionary is an associative array", in php array can be associative and also i can store info, in python can I do the same?
Do you know how can I resolve this script?

Answer (score 0):

Lets take them one by one.
Lists:
List is a very naive kind of data structure similar to arrays in other languages in terms of the way we write them like:

```
['a','b','c']
```

This is a list in python , but seems very similar to array structure.
However there is a very large difference in the way lists are used in python and the usual arrays.
Lists are heterogenous in nature. This means that we can store any kind of data simultaneously inside it like:

```
ls = [1,2,'a','g',True]
```

As you can see, we have various kinds of data within a list and is a valid list.
However, one important thing about them is that we can access the list items using zero based indices. So we can write:

```
print ls[0],ls[3]
output: 1 g
```

Dictionary:
This datastructure is similar to a hash map data structure. It contains a (key,Value) pair. An empty dictionary looks like:

```
dc = {}
```

Now, to store a key,value pair, e.g., ('potato',3),(tomato,5), we can do as:

```
dc['potato'] = 3
dc['tomato'] = 5
```

and we saved the data in the dictionary dc.
The important thing is that we can even store another data structure element like a list within a dictionary like:

```
dc['list1'] = ls , where ls is the list defined above.
```

This shows the power of using dictionary.
In your case, you have difined a dictionary like this:

```
data = {'type':[],'id':[]}
```

This means that your dictionary will consist of only two keys and each key corresponds to a list, which are empty for now.
Talking a bit about your script, the expression :

```
current_row_string[-8:]
```

doesn't make a sense. The index should have been -6 instead of -8 that would give you the id part of the current row.
This part is the id and should have been stored in a variable say :

```
id = current_row_string[-6:]
```

Further action can be performed as seen the answer given by Roland.